# rbenv - help understanding .ruby-version syntax "x.x.x" vs "ruby-x.x.x@project-name"

Tags: ruby, rbenv

When I create a project, and set my `rbenv local 2.2.2`, it'll create a `.ruby-version` file with `2.2.2` in it. Sometimes when I'm working on an existing project someone else created, the `.ruby-version` file will look something like `ruby-2.3.4@projectname`. If I try to `rbenv install` that, it obviously doesn't exist. If I just install the version, i.e. `rbenv install 2.3.4`, it installs, but when I set `rbenv local 2.3.4`, it changes `.ruby-version` to `2.3.4`, and not `ruby-2.3.4@projectname`.

Beyond the mild git annoyance of having that modified file there. What causes this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes when I'm working on an existing project **someone else** created, the `.ruby-version` file will look something like `ruby-2.3.4@projectname`

*Someone else* wasn't using `rbenv`. They were probably using [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version). From the docs:

> When in RVM, `.ruby-version` also supports gemsets in the form of `ruby@gemset` but this is not compatible with other Ruby Versions Managers. Another file might be used to specify the gemset without breaking compatibility - `.ruby-gemset`

For compatibility, it's best to only store the the version number in that file. So no, you're not doing anything wrong.

Alternatively, you can also specify the ruby version directly in the `Gemfile` with:

```
ruby '2.3.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Notation like `ruby-2.3.4@projectname` is from RVM. It says that you are using `ruby version 2.3.4` and local gemset `projectname`. It provides ability to create sets of gems with required versions relatively to each project.

Also simply `ruby-2.3.4` means that used global gemset, it can be written as `ruby-2.3.4@global`.